# Get line with starts with some number

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file and I have to process this file, but I have to pick just the last line of the file, and check if this line begins with the number 9, how can I do this using linq ... ?

This record, which begins with the number 9, can sometimes, not be the last line of the file, because the last line can be a \r\n

I maded one simple system to make thsi:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("9"))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But, I whant to know if is possible to make something more fast... or, more better, using linq... :)

Comment: why not check it while reading the file? Or you have some line collection which has been already read?

Comment: This isn't something you should be using linq for. Simply parse the file and check the last line.

Comment: I made some editons in question... :)

Comment: linq is just convenient and is not always the best (fastest, most efficient) but always shortest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string output=File.ReadAllLines(path)
                  .Last(x=>!Regex.IsMatch(x,@"^[\r\n]*$")); 
if(output.StartsWith("9"))//found
```

Comment: you made a typo `StartsWith` not `StartWith`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are fine, but the following is more intuitive to me (I love self-documenting code):

**Edit:** misinterpreted your question, updating my example code to be more appropriate

```
var nonEmptyLines =
  from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
  where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim())
  select line;

if (nonEmptyLines.Any())
{
  var lastLine = nonEmptyLines.Last();
  if (lastLine.StartsWith("9")) // or char.IsDigit(lastLine.First()) for 'any number'
  {
    // Your logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ something like following should work:

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("yourpath");
if(char.IsDigit(fileLines[fileLines.Count() - 1][0])
{
     //last line starts with a digit. 
}
```

Or for checking against specific digit `9` you can do:

```
if(fileLines.Last().StartsWith("9"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(list.Last(x =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).StartsWith("9"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to check the last two lines (in case the last line is a newline), you can do this. You can change `lines` to however many last lines you want to check.

```
int lines = 2;
if(File.ReadLines(file).Reverse().Take(lines).Any(x => x.StartsWith("9")))
{
    //one of the last X lines starts with 9
}
else
{
    //none of the last X lines start with 9
}
```